# Test point map for BBC micro:bit

Tags: schematics, testing

Does anyone have a map of the test points on the BBC micro:bit?

Specifically, I'd like to connect a scope to the lines from the nRF51's UART to the USB chip, which the [published schematic](https://github.com/bbcmicrobit/hardware/blob/master/SCH_BBC-Microbit_V1.3B.pdf) suggests are connected to two test points.  Among other things, that will enable us to measure the inter-character delay caused by interrupt handling vs polling and simultanously see the output on a host computer.

I'm not reluctant to probe around myself, but I'd rather save some time ...

Comment: The NRF51 on the micro:bit can map its UART functios to *any* GPIO pin. Not sure why you would need to probe stuff here.

Comment: The default baud rate doesn't match the docs, from what I remember...

Comment: @SeanHoulihane I seem to remember the same (9600 vs 115200 baud?), but I'm not using any of the supplied firmware, so that's not bothering me.  If I pin down the source of the inconsistency, I will be sure to post it somewhere.

Comment: @MikeSpivey Updated my answer. Concur on 9600 Baud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The testpoint map is available in [this PR](https://github.com/bbcmicrobit/hardware/pull/2/files), which seems to be stalled on getting merged (which would explain why you haven't found it).

[image: Microbit test point map]

This image is Copyright BBC, CC-CY-4.0

The signal names are as follows, according to the schematic.

```
 1 TMS  -- Debug interface for KL26
 2 TDO  --  "
 3 TDI  --  "
 4 TCLK --  "
 5 RST* --  "
 6 TGT_SWDIO
 7 TGT_SWCLK
 8 KL26 XTAL -- has 16MHz sine wave
 9 GND
10 VBUS_IF -- carries 5V when USB plugged in
11 USB-D+
12 USB-D-
13 VBAT
14 +V_TGT
15 TGT_TX -- UART transmit from nRF51
16 +3.3V_IF
17 TGT_RX -- UART receive from nRF51
18 VBAT
19 GND
20 TGT_RESET
21 GND
22 GND
```

In particular, the two UART lines are accessible at TP15 and TP17.